# Azure DataFactory Foreach Copy Upsert, how to create and use key column

Tags: sql-server, foreach, azure-data-factory, schema, pipeline

I have multiple tables, and I want to create a key column for each table that will be used dynamically for upsert

This is a preview of a list of all tables. In all these tables, we need to create key columns that will be used as key columns for upsert operations.
[image]

Comment: I how to create key columns and how to use it dynamically(upsert) for multiples table

Answer (score 0):

To upsert multiple tables in ADF, you need to get the keys of the respective tables.

Here I am using primary key as the key to upsert. I am using the below query to get the list of tables and their primary keys.

```
select C.* FROM  
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T  
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C  
ON C.CONSTRAINT_NAME=T.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

[image]

These are my tables:

**sample1:**

[image]

**sample2:**

[image]

Give the lookup array to ForEach activity.

I have source csv files with same name as tables name. So, I have used dataset parameters for the filename and given the expression like below for the filename.

```
@concat(item().TABLE_NAME,'.csv')
```

[image]

In sink also, I have used dataset parameters for the schema name and table name.

[image]

The Key columns dynamic content only accepts array. So, give our key column as an array `@createArray(item().COLUMN_NAME)`.

Execute the pipeline and you can see my table values were upserted.

**sample1:**

[image]

**sample2:**

[image]